# What happens to the consumer offset when an error occurs within a custom class in a KStream topology?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm aware that you can define stream-processing Kafka application in the form of a *topology* that implicitly understands which record has gone through successfully, and therefore can correctly commit the consumer offset so that when the microservice has to be restarted, it will continue reading the input toppic without missing messages.

But what happens when I introduce my own processing classes into the stream? For instance, perhaps I need to submit information from the input records to a web service with a big startup time. So I write my own processor class that accumulates, say, 1000 messages and then submits a batch request to the external service, like this.

```
    KStream<String, Prediction> stream = new StreamsBuilder()
        .stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new MessageSerde()))

        // talk to web service
        .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>("", wrapper.consume(v.getPayload())))
        .flatMapValues((ValueMapper<List<Prediction>, Iterable<Prediction>>) value -> value);

        // send downstream
        stream.peek((k, v) -> metrics.countOutgoingMessage())
        .to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new PredictionSerde()));
```

Assuming that the external service can issue zero, one or more predictions of some kind for every input, and that my wrapper submits inputs in batches to increase throughput. It seems to me that KStream cannot possibly keep track of which input record corresponds to which output record, and therefore no matter how it is implemented, it cannot guarantee that the correct consumer offset for the input topic is committed.

So in this paradigm, how can I give the library hints about which messages have been successfully processed? Or failing that, how can I get access to the consumer offset for the topic and perform commits explicitly so that no data loss can occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would might have a problem if you are using map. combining remote calls in a DSL operator is not recommended.  You might want to look into using the Processor API [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html). With `ProcessorContext` you can `forward` or `commit` which could give you flexibility you need.